# Deleting row involving joining of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I delete userID 00002 from Product ordered when I provided "Tim" (WHERE userName = 'Tim'). Not the userID, I'm very aware of it.

```
User Info
------------------
userID | userName 
00001  | Jim
00002  | Tim
00003  | Steve
00004  | Boo

Product Ordered
------------------
userID  | ProductCode
00002   | p0001
00002   | p0003
00001   | p0002
00003   | p0001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE po.*
FROM `Product ordered` po
INNER JOIN `User Info` ui
    ON ui.userID = po.userID
WHERE ui.userName = 'Tim'
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM product_ordered
WHERE userID IN (
  SELECT userID FROM user_info
  WHERE userName='Tim'
)
```